# Adding ImageView to RelativeLayout dynamically : Not Visible

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am adding `ImageView` to relative layout dynamically in my code.
But this imageView is sometime visible and sometimes not. I could see while debugging that image is getting added to the layout.

i even used `invalidate();` `refreshDrawable();` but for no avail.

any idea or help will be highly appreciated.

Firstly, i am removing previously added image to relative layout..

```
int size=   lv_header.getChildCount();
        for(int i=size;i>=0;i--)
        {
            if(lv_header.getChildAt(i) instanceof ImageView)
                {   if(lv_header.getChildAt(i)!=null){
                            lv_header.removeViewAt(i);
                        break;
                    }

            }

        }
```

and afterwards, i am adding new imageView..

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,v.getId());

            lv_header.addView(imageButton,lp);
            imageButton.refreshDrawableState();
            lv_header.invalidate();
```

Comment: Can you please post the part of your code where you do the creation and addition of the ImageView?

Comment: @GabriellaAngelova code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're replacing one ImageView with another?
Why not just keep the original ImageView and change it's drawable source with setImageDrawable() or setImageBitmap() ?

Comment: This image view is also getting created dynamically in fragment...and from fragmnet through interface i am added this in relative layout....current requirment is like this only

Comment: `activityImageView.setImageDrawable(fragmentImageView.getDrawable())` ??

Comment: one strange thing i noticed..there is one  help icon that shows help image over main view..once i click on that help image (and sets visibilty to GONE)  i could see that added image in relative layout